# Javascript Override CSS style not working on keyframe animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem for override CSS style on element that has class.

I'm using `keyframe` animation CSS class.

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8t52h0nm/2/) out for live action :

HTML :

```
<div id="sidebar" class="animation">this is sidebar</div>
<div id="trigger">this is trigger</div>
```

CSS :

```
#sidebar {width:225px; height:100%; background:red; position:fixed; top:0; left:0; display:none; }
#trigger {float:right; }
.animation {animation-duration: 0.5s; animation-fill-mode: both; }

@keyframes slideInLeft {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }

  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }

}

.slideInLeft {
  animation-name:slideInLeft;
  display:block !important;
}
```

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#trigger").on("click", function() { // trigger for opening #sidebar
        $("#sidebar").addClass("slideInLeft"); // addClass, so it animated
    });

    $("#sidebar").on("mousemove", function(e) { // move #sidebar according mousemove
        e.preventDefault(); // reset default behavior
        $(this).css("transform", "translate3D(" + e.pageX + "px, 0, 0)") 
        // add style for move #sidebar, look at this element, not working. what's wrong here?
    });
});
```

Why `#sidebar` not moving? the CSS style already add to it. but not moving.

What's wrong with my code?

thanks in advance...

Comment: you just need to add this jquery in to your code $(this).removeClass('slideInLeft'); under mousemove function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
animation-fill-mode: both;
```

Means that the sidebar will keep the style while animation end! If you remove animation-fill-mode style everything's ok.

more information for [animation-fill-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode).

Comment: so, i just need set it into `animation-fill-mode:none;` ?

Comment: this method really simple,  i like that! thank you so much Steel Liao!

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the class `slideInLeft` after the animation is complete.

```
$("#trigger").on("click", function() { // trigger for opening #sidebar
    $("#sidebar").addClass("slideInLeft block"); // addClass, so it animated
    setTimeout(function(){
            $("#sidebar").removeClass('slideInLeft');
    }, 500);
});
```

Also add a different class to keep the `display:block`.

```
.block{
    display: block !important;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/8t52h0nm/6/)

Answer (score 1):

It is because div have `slideInLeft` class. Remove it on mouse move.

```
$(this).removeClass('slideInLeft');
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8t52h0nm/5/)**

```
$("#sidebar").on("mousemove", function(e) { 
   e.preventDefault(); 
   $(this).removeClass('slideInLeft');
   $(this).css("transform", "translate3D(" + e.pageX + "px, 0, 0)") 
});
```

Comment: wow, this method also working! amazing! thank you so much ketan!

Answer (score 1):

the animation in the class slideInLeft will prevent your updates from showing.

if you change the css update code to this you'll see results. You still need the display:block so just removing the class would not work.

```
$(this).removeClass('slideInLeft');
$(this).css({"display":"block","transform": "translate3D(" + e.pageX + "px, 0, 0)"}) // add style for move #sidebar, look at this element, not working. what's wrong here?
```

changes applied https://jsfiddle.net/e9tzurnf/

Comment: Wow, fabolous! so, i must display block to it. thanks Ekim